# ActiveX/OCX can't read from disk

Tags: activex, ocx

I just need some ideas/hints that push me into the right direction. Since the whole story is a bit more complicated I make it short: I have an OCX that itself uses a more complex DLL. When running this ActiveX it seems disk read operations fail (but I'm not 100% sure if this is the reason) and the underlying DLL causes crashes on some strange positions in code.

So my question: are there any special permissions/manifest information/whatever needed for such an ActiveX when running it with Windows 7?

Thanks!

Comment: You should have at least specified what is the execution environment (the host) where your run your ActiveX. IE? VB6? Office? WinForms? WPF? etc.

Comment: Yes...sorry, it is plain C++ in VS6 (yes, I know, quite old, but its not my decision to use it or not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved, is was a problem of incompatible libraries that caused a crash on a strange position in code.